# Retrieve all workbook names during more than one excel instances are running

Tags: vb.net, excel

This question is basically regarding to loop all workbooks in all excel instances!

Comment: Create an array and store workbook to it as you open each one? Or even key it with dictionary for faster retrieval later instead of looping?

Comment: Maybe this'll help? http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=182853

Comment: You are only ever going to get one... You are looping `Excel` processes, but ***not*** doing anything with them once found. You create a new object of `ExcelApplication` and by default it's **1** workbook. This is why you only ever see one book...

Comment: Even the Windows API? Might be hard to find what you're looking for _if_ there isn't any simple solution.

Comment: @Markowitz Can you use API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main issue you are facing is you are not using any of the process's you come across. Therefore, you will not get anything that way. Inside of the loop for the process's you then create a new instance of `ExcelApplication` and then try to loop through the `Workbooks`. By default when you do this there is only **1** at that time, hence why you get only **1** `Workbook` and also why you will only ever see **1** `Workbook`.

**Solution (Tried & Tested)**

You need to look into ***Windows API*** calls to get what you need. A few of them are:

1. **GetDesktopWindow()**
2. **EnumChildWindows()**
3. **GetClassName()**
4. **EnumWindowsProc()**
5. [**AccessibleObjectFromWindow()**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317978(v=vs.85).aspx)

   ```
   Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
   Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

   Public Class Form1

   Private Declare Function GetDesktopWindow Lib "user32" () As Integer
   Private Declare Function EnumChildWindows Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal WindowHandle As IntPtr, ByVal Callback As EnumWindowsProc, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Boolean
   Private Declare Function GetClassName Lib "user32.dll" Alias "GetClassNameA" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Integer) As Integer
   Private Delegate Function EnumWindowsProc(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As Int32) As Boolean
   Private Declare Function AccessibleObjectFromWindow Lib "oleacc" (ByVal Hwnd As Int32, ByVal dwId As Int32, ByRef riid As Guid, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)> ByRef ppvObject As Object) As Int32

   Private Const OBJID_NATIVE = &HFFFFFFF0

   'Required to show the workbooks. Used in function to add to.
   Private lstWorkBooks As New List(Of String)

   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
       lstWorkBooks.Clear()
       GetExcelOpenWorkBooks()
   End Sub


   Private Sub GetExcelOpenWorkBooks()
       Try
           'Get handle to desktop
           Dim WindowHandle As IntPtr = GetDesktopWindow()

           'Enumerate through the windows (objects) that are open
           EnumChildWindows(WindowHandle, AddressOf GetExcelWindows, 0)

           'List the workbooks out if we have something
           If lstWorkBooks.Count > 0 Then MsgBox(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lstWorkBooks))

       Catch ex As Exception
       End Try

   End Sub

   Public Function GetExcelWindows(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As Int32) As Boolean

       Dim Ret As Integer = 0
       Dim className As String = Space(255) 'Return the string with some padding...

       Ret = GetClassName(hwnd, className, 255)
       className = className.Substring(0, Ret)

       If className = "EXCEL7" Then
           Dim ExcelApplication As Excel.Application
           Dim ExcelObject As Object = Nothing
           Dim IDispatch As Guid

           AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hwnd, OBJID_NATIVE, IDispatch, ExcelObject)

           'Did we get anything?
           If ExcelObject IsNot Nothing Then
               ExcelApplication = ExcelObject.Application
               'Make sure we have the instance...
               If ExcelApplication IsNot Nothing Then
                   'Go through the workbooks...
                   For Each wrk As Excel.Workbook In ExcelApplication.Workbooks
                       'If workbook ins't in the list then add it...
                       If Not lstWorkBooks.Contains(wrk.Name) Then
                           lstWorkBooks.Add(wrk.Name)
                       End If
                   Next
               End If

           End If
       End If

       Return True

   End Function

   End Class
   ```

Comment: Seriously, `I prefer vb.net code without API. But if this is not possible I accept API solution`. What is the problem? This ***answer's your issue and more***. `I prefer simple code` I wish it was that easy, if you think that's the case you have a long way to the top :)

Comment: @Codexer You should have deleted the answer since he appears ungrateful that you solved his issue.

Comment: @Markowitz Thank you, accepting answer's is how it works here. If it's helped, it is important to vote and accept answer. This helps other coming along that may have the same issue. Also without using API it's probably impossible to loop through active windows and getting that object, the only way I know of is what I posted