# Get running instances of Excel with VB.NET

Tags: excel, vb.net, exception, com, excel-interop

I have the following working code taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36267576):

```
Option Compare Binary
Option Explicit On
Option Infer On
Option Strict Off

Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Friend Module Module1
    Private Declare Function GetDesktopWindow Lib "user32" () As IntPtr
    Private Declare Function EnumChildWindows Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal WindowHandle As IntPtr, ByVal Callback As EnumWindowsProc, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Boolean
    Private Declare Function GetClassName Lib "user32.dll" Alias "GetClassNameA" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Integer) As Integer
    Private Delegate Function EnumWindowsProc(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As Int32) As Boolean
    Private Declare Function AccessibleObjectFromWindow Lib "oleacc" (ByVal Hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal dwId As Int32, ByRef riid As Guid, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)> ByRef ppvObject As Object) As Int32
    Private lstWorkBooks As New List(Of String)
    Public Sub Main()
        GetExcelOpenWorkBooks()
    End Sub
    Private Sub GetExcelOpenWorkBooks()
        EnumChildWindows(GetDesktopWindow(), AddressOf GetExcelWindows, CType(0, IntPtr))
        If lstWorkBooks.Count > 0 Then MsgBox(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lstWorkBooks))
    End Sub
    Public Function GetExcelWindows(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As Int32) As Boolean
        Dim Ret As Integer = 0
        Dim className As String = Space(255)
        Ret = GetClassName(hwnd, className, 255)
        className = className.Substring(0, Ret)
        If className = "EXCEL7" Then
            Dim ExcelApplication As Excel.Application
            Dim ExcelObject As Object = Nothing
            Dim IDispatch As Guid
            AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hwnd, &HFFFFFFF0, IDispatch, ExcelObject)
            If ExcelObject IsNot Nothing Then
                ExcelApplication = ExcelObject.Application
                If ExcelApplication IsNot Nothing Then
                    For Each wrk As Excel.Workbook In ExcelApplication.Workbooks
                        If Not lstWorkBooks.Contains(wrk.Name) Then
                            lstWorkBooks.Add(wrk.Name)
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            End If
        End If
        Return True
    End Function
End Module
```

It will be used to get references of all the opened/running Excel instances/applications.

Without looking it up online I would never guess how to do it as I don't understand much of it, so it's probably not the best way to do it and is [bug/error prone](https://www.quora.com/Which-is-the-most-Bug-prone-algorithm-to-code/answer/Jonathan-Paulson). **I'm trying to turn [option strict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) on** ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/222478), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A22656+strict+on)) so I changed the line `ExcelApplication = ExcelObject.Application` to `ExcelApplication = CType(ExcelObject, Excel.Application).Application` but doing so throws the exception:

> **[System.InvalidCastException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.invalidcastexception)** Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application'. This operation failed because the Query Interface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{000208D5-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

I can find multiple look alike references to this in different sites but haven't got the luck to fix it with the [trial and error method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_and_error).

My question is how to [turn on option strict](https://blog.codinghorror.com/option-strict-and-option-explicit-in-vbnet-2005/) and bonus if someone helps me get a better code or fix/explain any other issues with it.

Comment: 1) You see that `Catch` with *nothing* in it? That wil tell you *nothing* about problems encountered. Remove the Try..Catch and see if you get a useful error message. 2) Option Infer On is your friend; if there is some requirement for explicit declarations, you can get your program working and then go back and add those declarations. 3) I expect that you want to iterate over the items returned in `ExcelObject` somehow.

Comment: Do you mean, you want to find all opened WorkBooks? Or check whether there are undisposed Excel instances hanging aroud? Both? Btw, that code can be simplified a lot, without using PInvoke at all. A `Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")` returns an object that can be cast to an `Excel.Application` interop COM object. The list of processes (`Process.GetProcessesByName()`) will return all instances. The undisposed ones will have a `MainWindowHandle = 0`.

Comment: @Jimi I want to have a reference to all the Excel instances so I can have access to anything from them (workbooks, worksheets, cells, etc). When I use `Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")` it only returns the active object (1 instead of all). When I use `Process.GetProcessesByName("excel")` it gives a list of the processes and then when I use `.MainWindowHandle` it returns something like `hwnd` from the function `GetExcelWindows` in the code above but a bit different. In the try I made the correct was `66888`, but I would get `66760` with that method. Can you please provide some code?

Comment: @AndrewMorton After giving it a second thought on what you said I followed both advises. And yes I want to have access to all the opened running instances/processes of Excel which the code already does but I can't figure out how to make it work with strict on.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by *all instances*. Excel has one instance that handles multiple workbooks (which you can access with `Excel.Application = CType(Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application"), Excel.Application)`). When using Interop (in your code) to open a WorkBook, you create a different, window-less Process, which will remain active until you release (`Marshal.ReleaseComObject()`) all its objects. If you fail to Marshal/Release those objects, that Interop process won't be GC Collected. Are you referring to these (unreleased) objects?

Comment: @Jimi That might be it. I think my older code (when I understood 0 of all of this) probably is what sometimes made a new window-less Excel process and would hold it even after closing the form/program which is why I would get confused. So, as long as I make sure the code releases the COM objects there will always only exist 1 Excel process right. I think I understand it now. Not sure if I should close the question or if you want to give an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @Jimi It's exactly that. I just did some tests with the application/program without modifying my old code and got a [window-less Excel background process](https://i.imgur.com/5xIsRHk.png) (which now that I understand all of this a bit better I know I need to release them and also just in case before getting the active Excel object I'm going to dispose of the processes without a window -- `MainWindowHandle = 0`). Thank you! I learned a lot on this which was really confusing for me before.

Comment: Well, you're not alone. You can see this all the time. That's because (especially with Excel) it can be difficult to understand that you're creating an new/different Interop object. Almost impossible if you use type inference. That's why you can find all sort of discussions on which is the *best way* to release an Excel Interop process. What I can do is to show you a way to access the WorkBooks of the *legit* Excel process through its active `Application` instance + how to release it. If someone won't come by in the meanwhile.

Comment: @Jimi Can you help me make sure [this code](https://pastebin.com/1ukgSz9j) is ok? To get rid of the window-less processes should I only use `Process.Dispose()`? And also, when there's no Excel open I get a `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException` unless I ignore it with a `Try...Catch` around the `Marshal.GetActiveObject`. Is there a better way for that?

Comment: You shouldn't find yourself in need to `.Kill()` an Excel process in the first place. Which processes? Yours? Some other appllications'?. Give me a moment (or two), and I'll post some examples on how to handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51791847) which I had previously marked as accepted is great, but there is a catch ([*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/8560)), which is that it only gets the active object, the first Excel process.

That is enough in most cases, but not in a specific one where there is more than one instance of Excel opened. From what I know, that is only possible by either holding the `Alt` key when starting Excel which prompts to start Excel in a new instance, or with code in some program.

On the other hand the code in the question does work and solve the issue of getting all running instances of Excel. The only problem that I was having was converting it from late binding (`Option Strict Off`) to early binding (`Option Strict On`) which was causing an error that I couldn't find the answer to, until now.

With the help of an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/779710) in another question that approaches the issue in C# I found out that I had to replace the parameter `ppvObject` of the function `AccessibleObjectFromWindow` from:

```
<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)> ByRef ppvObject As Object
```

To:

```
ByRef ppvObject As Excel.Window
```

And change the type of the variable `ExcelObject` in the declaration from `Object` to `Excel.Window` (also good practice to rename it to `ExcelWindow` in the code).

Answer (score 6):

About the primary objective, accessing the opened WorkBooks of an existing Excel instance (created running `EXCEL.EXE`. Which of course includes a request to the Shell to open an Excel-associated file extension).

> The following method uses `Console.WriteLine()` just to evaluate
> (eventually setting a BreakPoint), the current values of some objects.
> It's clearly redundant (has to be deleted/commented out before
> release).

It creates a local `List(Of Workbook)`, which is the returned to the caller:
Note that each time an Interop object is created is then marshalled and set to nothing.
Why both? Inspect the objects when debugging and you'll see.

The [Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL")](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname) is also redundant. Again, used only to evaluate the returned `Process` objects and inspect their values.

The Excel active Instance (if any) is accessed using [Marshal.GetActiveObject()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getactiveobject)
Note that this will **not** create a new Process. We are accessing the existing instance.

`Visual Studio Version: 15.7.6 - 15.8.3`
`.Net FrameWork version: 4.7.1`
`Option Strict: On, Option Explicit: On, Option Infer: On`

```
Public Function FindOpenedWorkBooks() As List(Of Workbook)
    Dim OpenedWorkBooks As New List(Of Workbook)()

    Dim ExcelInstances As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL")
    If ExcelInstances.Count() = 0 Then
        Return Nothing
    End If

    Dim ExcelInstance As Excel.Application = TryCast(Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application"), Excel.Application)
    If ExcelInstance Is Nothing Then Return Nothing
    Dim worksheets As Sheets = Nothing
    For Each WB As Workbook In ExcelInstance.Workbooks
        OpenedWorkBooks.Add(WB)
        worksheets = WB.Worksheets
        Console.WriteLine(WB.FullName)
        For Each ws As Worksheet In worksheets
            Console.WriteLine(ws.Name)
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ws)
        Next
    Next

    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(worksheets)
    worksheets = Nothing
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(ExcelInstance)
    Marshal.CleanupUnusedObjectsInCurrentContext()
    ExcelInstance = Nothing
    Return OpenedWorkBooks
End Function
```

The returned `List(Of Workbook)` contains active objects. Those objects have not been marshalled and are accessible.

You can call the `FindOpenedWorkBooks()` method like this:
(Some values, as `WorkSheet.Columns.Count`, are worthless. Those are used to show that you access each [WorkSheet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheet) values in each of the [Sheets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.sheets) returned, for all the [WorkBooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbook) found)

The `Excel.Range` object created to access the value of a Cell (the first Column Header, here):
`Dim CellRange As Excel.Range = CType(ws.Cells(1, 1), Excel.Range)` is a new Interop object, so it is released after its value has been evaluated.

```
Private ExcelWorkBooks As List(Of Workbook) = New List(Of Workbook)()

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ExcelWorkBooks = FindOpenedWorkBooks()

    If ExcelWorkBooks IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim WBNames As New StringBuilder()
        For Each wb As Workbook In ExcelWorkBooks
            WBNames.AppendLine(wb.Name)
            Dim sheets As Sheets = wb.Worksheets
            Console.WriteLine($"Sheets No.: { sheets.Count}")
            For Each ws As Worksheet In sheets
                Console.WriteLine($"WorkSheet Name: {ws.Name}  Columns: {ws.Columns.Count}  Rows: {ws.Rows.Count}")
                Dim CellRange As Excel.Range = CType(ws.Cells(1, 1), Excel.Range)
                Console.WriteLine(CellRange.Value2.ToString)
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(CellRange)
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ws)
            Next

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sheets)
        Next
        MessageBox.Show(WBNames.ToString())
    End If
End Sub
```

What objects must be Released? All the objects you create.

Suppose you have to open a new Excel file and you want to access a `WorkBook` inside it.
(**This will create a new Process**)

```
Dim WorkBook1Path As String = "[Some .xlsx Path]"
Dim ExcelApplication As New Excel.Application()
Dim ExcelWorkbooks As Workbooks = ExcelApplication.Workbooks
Dim MyWorkbook As Workbook = ExcelWorkbooks.Open(WorkBook1Path, False)
Dim worksheets As Sheets = MyWorkbook.Worksheets
Dim MyWorksheet As Worksheet = CType(worksheets("Sheet1"), Worksheet)

'(...)
'Do your processing here
'(...)

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(MyWorksheet)
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(worksheets)
MyWorkbook.Close(False) 'Don't save
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(MyWorkbook)
ExcelWorkbooks.Close()
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ExcelWorkbooks)
ExcelApplication.Quit()
Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(ExcelApplication)
Marshal.CleanupUnusedObjectsInCurrentContext()
```

Again, all objects must be released. `WorkBooks` must be [`.Close()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.close)d and their content saved if required. The `WorkBooks` collection must be `.Close()`d.
Use the `Excel.Application` main object [`.Quit()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.quit) method to notify the end of the operations.
**`.Quit()` will not terminate the Process you created**.
[`Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(ExcelApplication)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.finalreleasecomobject) is used to finalize it's release.
At this point the `EXCEL` process will end.

The last instruction, [Marshal.CleanupUnusedObjectsInCurrentContext()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.cleanupunusedobjectsincurrentcontext), is a clean-up precaution.
May not be even necessary, but it doesn't hurt: we're quitting here.

Of course you can instantiate all those objects once, in the initialization proc of you application, then Marshal them when the application closes.
When using a `Form` class, it creates a `Dispose()` method that can be used for this task.
If you are implementing these procedure in your own class, implement the [IDisposable interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable) and [implement the required Dispose() method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose).

But, what if you don't want or can't take care of all those objects instantiation/destruction?
Possibly, you prefer to use Type Inference when instantiating new objects. So you set `Option Explicit` and `Option Strict` `ON`, while keeping `Option Infer On`. Many do so.

So you write something like:
`Dim MyWorkbook = ExcelWorkbooks.Open([FilePath], False)`

instead of:
`Dim MyWorkbook As Workbook = ExcelWorkbooks.Open([FilePath], False)`

Sometimes it's clear what object(s) has(have) been created to satisfy your request.
Sometimes absolutely not.

Thus, many prefer to implement a different *pattern* to Release/Dispose Interop objects.

You can see many ways here (c#, mainly, but its the same):
[How do I properly clean up Excel interop objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-do-i-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects)

This thoughtful implementation:
[Application not quitting after calling quit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697282/application-not-quitting-after-calling-quit?answertab=active#tab-top)

Also, a peculiar way described by `TnTinMn` here:
[Excel COM Object not getting released](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36550446/vb-net-excel-com-object-not-getting-released?answertab=active#tab-top)

Test, find your way :).
Never use `Process.Kill()`. Among other things, you don't know what you're terminating.

*Also, some interesting readings about COM marshalling in managed/unmanaged code*:

**The Visual Studio Engineering Team:**
[Marshal.ReleaseComObject Considered Dangerous](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2010/03/01/marshal-releasecomobject-considered-dangerous/)

**Hans Passant on COM marshalling and Garbage Collection**:
[Understanding garbage collection in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130382/understanding-garbage-collection-in-net?answertab=active#tab-top)

**MSDN docs about Runtime Callable Wrapper (RCW) and COM Callable Wrapper (CCW)**
[Runtime Callable Wrapper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/8bwh56xe(v=vs.100))
[COM Callable Wrapper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/f07c8z1c(v=vs.100))

Comment: One thing that I did found out was that you can legitimately create an Excel instance in a different process that isn't window-less (`MainWindowHandle = 0`) without using any code. Just by holding the key `Alt` when opening Excel, a message pops up asking if you want to start a new instance of Excel. I didn't tried anything but I do believe that would be an issue to list the opened workbooks with the code provided in the answer & comments.